# Flash mouse click is too sensitive, clicked when scrolling

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Flash mouse click is too sensitive, clicked when scrolling

I am just wondering if mouse down would be different? Or what solution should i use?

I have a viewport that scrolls, and inside it there are boxes(Movieclips) and when i scroll, it clicks the MovieClip even i dont meant to, it is slightly too sensitive.

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN` event listener and check for `event.target` object. If it is scroll object , stop event's bubbling:

```
//inside of the listener, on top line
if( event.target === some_scroll_object ){
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```